Zoom meeting does not show my profile photo. How to fix?
In a Zoom meeting,  when I turn off my camera, Zoom should show instead my profile picture.
For everybody else in the meeting I am in at this moment,   it does show their profile pictures  when they turn off the camera. But for me, it only shows my name in that rectangle where my profile picture should have appeared. How do I fix it?
Actually some months ago it worked OK. I think I did not change anything in my settings.  Or is it a new recent bug in Zoom?

Edit your profile in Zoom, and reload your pic.
